# Sorting an Array with Selection Sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, declaration

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int selectionSort(int data[], int count)
{
  int a,b;
  int tmp;
  int minimum;
  for(a=0; a<count-1;a++){
  minimum = a;
    for(b=a+1;b<count;b++){
          if(data[minimum]>data[b]) {
            minimum = b;
            }
        }
        tmp = data[a];
        data[a]=data[minimum];
        data[minimum]=tmp;
}
  return 0;
}


int main(){
    int randomarray[10];
    int i;
    int k;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
    randomarray[i]=rand()%100;
    selectionSort(randomarray[i], k = 10 );
     printf("%d\n",randomarray[i]);

  }
return 0;

}
```

I am trying to create a program that sorts an array of random integers. I think there is a problem with the declaration of my function, but I am not used to using C. The errors are shown below:

```
semihosting_example.c:13:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'srand' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
semihosting_example.c:15:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rand' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
semihosting_example.c:16:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'selectionSort' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
semihosting_example.c:6:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[10]'ing_example.c:6:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int (*)[10]
```

Comment: You didn't include `<stdlib.h>` — that's the first two messages.

Comment: The argument is not type `int (*)[10]` but type `int`. Make sure you are compiling intended latest code.

Comment: Your indentation is erratic, which makes it hard to read your code.  Your loop in `main()` is weird; you sort the array on each iteration, telling the sort there are 10 values to be sorted, which is bogus.  Why you assign to `k` is anyone's guess; there's no obvious good reason to do so.  Your loop should cover the assignment to `randomArray[i]` only; the `selectionSort()` should be outside the loop.  The `printf()` probably needs to be replaced by its own loop.  And loops in C run `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` — that's idiomatic; the exceptions are rare.

Comment: `for(i=1; i<=10; i++)` Ouch, off-by-one error.

Comment: I added that header and the first two errors disappeared but the second 2 errors remain.

Comment: The last two warnings belong to a variant of your code where you wrote `selectionSort(&randomArray, k = 10);` (though the `k = 10` part is still ill-advised).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler could you explain how that variant of my code would produce those errors? Also how could I change the k assignment to something more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code with the appropriate HEADERS. I am trying to create a function with an array that calls the function with an array:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int selectionSort(int (*)[10], int count)
{
  int a,b;
  int tmp;
  int minimum;
  for(a=0; a<count-1;a++){
  minimum = a;
    for(b=a+1;b<count;b++){
          if(data[minimum]>data[b]) {
            minimum = b;
            }
        }
        tmp = data[a];
        data[a]=data[minimum];
        data[minimum]=tmp;
}
  return 0;
}


int main(){
    int randomarray[10];
    int i;
    int k;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
    randomarray[i]=rand()%100;
    selectionSort(randomarray[i], k = 10 );
     printf("%d\n",randomarray[i]);

  }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer — you should probably delete it.  You can edit extra information into a question, in general, but I don't think it is beneficial in this case.  If you edit a question, you mustn't invalidate answers.  It is OK to invalidate comments — they're officially 'ephemeral' and 'inconsequential' — though be cautious about even that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static void selectionSort(int data[], int count)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < count - 1; a++)
    {
        int minimum = a;
        for (int b = a + 1; b < count; b++)
        {
            if (data[minimum] > data[b])
                minimum = b;
        }
        int tmp = data[a];
        data[a] = data[minimum];
        data[minimum] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int randomarray[10];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        randomarray[i] = rand() % 100;

    printf("Before:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, randomarray[i]);
    selectionSort(randomarray, 10);
    printf("After:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, randomarray[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces output such as:

```
Before:
0: 73
1: 63
2: 73
3: 80
4: 28
5: 19
6: 63
7: 96
8: 82
9: 46
After:
0: 19
1: 28
2: 46
3: 63
4: 63
5: 73
6: 73
7: 80
8: 82
9: 96
```

Note that it prints the array before sorting as well as afterwards so that you can tell whether it sorted correctly.

The code doesn't use `k`; it declares variables as late as possible.

If you replace the line:

```
selectionSort(randomarray, 10);
```

with:

```
selectionSort(&randomarray, 10);
```

you get the error messages:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     sort53.c -o sort53 
sort53.c: In function ‘main’:
sort53.c:32:19: error: passing argument 1 of ‘selectionSort’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   32 |     selectionSort(&randomarray, 10);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   int (*)[10]
sort53.c:5:31: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[10]’
    5 | static void selectionSort(int data[], int count)
      |                           ~~~~^~~~~~
$
```

That's from GCC 10.1.0, but it is very similar to the error messages posted in the question.   If you instead replace the call with:

```
selectionSort(randomarray[0], 10);
```

then the error messages are:

```
sort53.c: In function ‘main’:
sort53.c:32:30: error: passing argument 1 of ‘selectionSort’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
   32 |     selectionSort(randomarray[0], 10);
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                              |
      |                              int
sort53.c:5:31: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    5 | static void selectionSort(int data[], int count)
      |                           ~~~~^~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```